# Fridge: frost build up on coils

Tags: refrigerator, diy-vs-pro

Our fridge started to get warmer a few days ago. Because we keep medicines for my daughter, I always keep a thermometer inside. From the usual 3C-5C that I used to see, over a few days the temperature crept up to about 11C now. Things are still frozen solid in the freezer.

Before calling a repair person, I tried to assess what is going on (not a lot of experience on fridges, but in the past I have successfully diagnosed and change a blown defrost thermostat). As suspected, there is ice buildup:

[image]

But, at the same time, there is less ice close to the defroster. I removed the defrost thermostat and it tested correctly (open when cold, closed when warm). I also positively tested conductivity on the defroster.

Is it obvious what is going on?

Comment: They have a defrost cycle when the coils are heated for several minutes to melt ice. This may be a timer that activates every couple days or something that counts how many times the door is opened, or some other mechanism . So either the coil heater does not work or the activation system does not work.

Comment: How old is the fridge?  Is "the person would pay for repair or new refrigerator" the same as "the person who pays the electric bill"?  This could be good news for that person.

Comment: Bought it used, so I don't know the exact date. Some 15 years old, I would say. I measured it at 140W and it's EnergyGuide placard says it consumes 700kW-h per year. Same person. Not sure what the good news are.